# How to add authentication to REST API

Tags: rest, api, authentication, restful-authentication

I am currently learning REST APIs, but I still quite don't understand how to authenticate clients when making calls to the API.

How developers usually do this?

please refer me to a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use OAuth 2 protocol for authentication. 
There are a lot of tutorials about how to implement it.

Link to OAuth website:

[OAuth](https://oauth.net/getting-started/)